# Row not returning NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, null, left-join

I am trying to select students along with a number of enrolled each one of them has. So if the student hasn't enrolled at all in any courses I want to display 0 or none. Before I can do this I want the row to return me null, but it is not happening. It is giving me the right result except I don't have a row that is null.

```
SELECT s.STUDENT_ID, z.COURSE_NO, e.ENROLL_DATE, COUNT(*) AS ENROLLED
FROM STUDENT s,ENROLLMENT e, SECTION z
WHERE s.STUDENT_ID = e.STUDENT_ID
AND e.SECTION_ID = z.SECTION_ID
AND s.PHONE LIKE '702%'
GROUP BY s.STUDENT_ID, z.COURSE_NO, e.ENROLL_DATE
```

So if it did return null for the students that haven't enrolled in any courses I wanted to do something like this

```
SELECT lt.STUDENT_ID,lt.FIRST_NAME, lt.LAST_NAME, NVL(COUNT(ENROLLED), 0) AS ENROLLED
FROM STUDENT lt
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT s.STUDENT_ID, z.COURSE_NO, e.ENROLL_DATE, COUNT(*) AS ENROLLED
FROM STUDENT s,ENROLLMENT e, SECTION z
WHERE s.STUDENT_ID = e.STUDENT_ID
AND e.SECTION_ID = z.SECTION_ID
AND s.PHONE LIKE '702%'
GROUP BY s.STUDENT_ID, z.COURSE_NO, e.ENROLL_DATE) rt
ON lt.STUDENT_ID = rt.STUDENT_ID
GROUP BY lt.STUDENT_ID,lt.FIRST_NAME, lt.LAST_NAME;
```

How do I get a row that returns null?

Comment: YOu should stop using implicit joins. THey are a asql antipattern and were repleced 20 years ago for goodness sakes. ANd never ever under any circumstance comnine implict and explicit joins or you wil very likely get incorrect results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.STUDENT_ID, z.COURSE_NO, e.ENROLL_DATE, COUNT(*) AS ENROLLED
FROM   STUDENT         s
LEFT   JOIN ENROLLMENT e ON e.STUDENT_ID = s.STUDENT_ID 
LEFT   JOIN SECTION    z ON z.SECTION_ID = e.SECTION_ID
WHERE  s.PHONE LIKE '702%'
GROUP  BY s.STUDENT_ID, z.COURSE_NO, e.ENROLL_DATE
```

[Details in the language reference.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries006.htm#i2054062)

Comment: that solves the problem...whatever query I have used I always get the same answer. that really helped..thanks!